# How to figure out where to put "..." if text is bigger than container

Tags: c#, winforms, algorithm, text, label

Let's say I have a `Label` inside a `Panel`. The text is going to be bigger than the `Panel` sometimes, but not always. How would I figure out what part of the text I should at "..." in front of without hard-coding exactly how many characters it would take, because each character isnt the same size.

```
if (bigLabel.Width >= this.ClientRectangle.Width - 10) {
    dotLabel.Location = new Point(this.ClientRectangle.Width - 10 - dotLabel.Width);
}
else {
    dotLabel.Location = new Point(this.Width + 10, this.Height + 10);
}
```

Comment: I tried putting a second label on top of it near the end of the label that has "..." and i would check how big the text is and only show it if the other label is a certain number of pixels big, but that makes it look cut off too. like there would be half of a "B" and a dot on top of it, and i tried counting the characters and splitting it but that sometimes doesn't use up all of the space

Comment: Please post the code you have and we can take a look at your problem more accurately

Comment: By the way, kudos to you for learning programming at such a young age, I wish I had!

Comment: Looks like Hans has the solution for you there. Like he says, just let the `TextRender` figure that out for you on its own :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leave it up to TextRenderer.DrawText() to figure that out itself.  Specify the TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis option.  You'll find a code sample in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903172/indicate-truncation-in-tooltipstatuslabel-automatically/2904279#2904279).

Which is already built in to the Label control.  Set its AutoSize property to False and AutoEllipis property to True to have it all done automatically.  And you get a tooltip for free that shows the missing text.

Comment: as a follow up question, is it possible to replace the 3 dots with something else, like a dash, or just 2 dots using this method?

Comment: No, the ellipsis is a dedicated Unicode glyph, codepoint U+2026.  It means only one thing, dashes and dots are Morse code that mean something else :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Graphics.DrawString method (TextRenderer.DrawText is a GDI way, Graphics.DrawString - GDI+). Set StringFormat.Trimming property to StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter (EllipsisWord, EllipsisPath).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Telerik control - RadLabel, Only set this properties:

```
this.lblReferralTracking.TextAlignment = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
this.lblReferralTracking.TextWrap = false;
this.lblReferralTracking.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
```